# How can I get filename with WinHttp?

Tags: c++, http, winapi, get, winhttp

I want to download files using winhttp lib. When I send GET requests I don't get in header filename. In CreateFile, I need to insert the original filename. I need 'Content-length" too, It is included in the header. I use WINHTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH in WinHttpQueryHeaders().

```
DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    LPBYTE pszOutBuffer;

    BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET  hSession = NULL, hConnect = NULL, hRequest = NULL;

    hSession = WinHttpOpen( L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
                            WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY, 
                            WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, 
                            WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 
                            0 );
    if( hSession )
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect( hSession,
                                   L"www.teapotnet.org",
                                   INTERNET_DEFAULT_PORT,
                                   0 );
    if( hConnect )
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest( hConnect,
                                       L"GET",
                                       L"/download/?release=win32&update=1  ",
                                       NULL,
                                       WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
                                       NULL,
                                       NULL );

    if( hRequest )
        bResults = WinHttpAddRequestHeaders( hRequest,
                                             L"Content-Disposition:",
                                             (ULONG)-1L,
                                             WINHTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD );

    if( hRequest )
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest( hRequest,
                                       L"Content-Disposition:",
                                       (ULONG)-1L,
                                       WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA,
                                       0,
                                       WINHTTP_IGNORE_REQUEST_TOTAL_LENGTH,
                                       0 );
    if( bResults )
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse( hRequest, NULL );
    // Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( L"C:/Users/Nikita/Desktop/teapotnet-0.11.4-win32.zip",
                               GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                               FILE_SHARE_READ, 
                               NULL,
                               OPEN_ALWAYS,
                               FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                               NULL );
    UINT total = 0;
    if( bResults )
    {
        WinHttpQueryHeaders( hRequest,
                             WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF,
                             WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX,
                             NULL,
                             &dwSize,
                             WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX );
        if( GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER )
        {
            WCHAR* lpOutBuffer = new WCHAR[dwSize / sizeof( WCHAR )];

            bResults = WinHttpQueryHeaders( hRequest,
                                            WINHTTP_QUERY_RAW_HEADERS_CRLF,
                                            WINHTTP_HEADER_NAME_BY_INDEX,
                                            lpOutBuffer,
                                            &dwSize,
                                            WINHTTP_NO_HEADER_INDEX );
            std::wstring str( lpOutBuffer );
            int i = 0;
        }
        do
        {
            // Check for available data.        
            dwSize = 0;
            if( !WinHttpQueryDataAvailable( hRequest, &dwSize ) )
                printf( "Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n", GetLastError() );

            total += dwSize;

            pszOutBuffer = new byte[dwSize + 1];
            if( !pszOutBuffer )
            {
                printf( "Out of memory\n" );
                dwSize = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // Read the Data.            
                ZeroMemory( pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1 );
                if( !WinHttpReadData( hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer, dwSize, &dwDownloaded ) )
                {
                    printf( "Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError() );
                }
                else
                {
                    //printf("%s", pszOutBuffer); 
                    DWORD wmWritten;
                    bool fr = WriteFile( hFile, pszOutBuffer, dwSize, &wmWritten, NULL );
                    int n = GetLastError();
                }
                // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.            
                delete[] pszOutBuffer;
            }
        } while( dwSize > 0 );
    }
    CloseHandle( hFile );
    // Report any errors.
    if( !bResults )
        printf( "Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError() );
    // Close any open handles.
    if( hRequest ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hRequest );
    if( hConnect ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hConnect );
    if( hSession ) WinHttpCloseHandle( hSession );
```

Comment: HTTP is a fairly complicated protocol, but it is fully specified in [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616). It is not practical to attempt to use an HTTP client library without a full and complete understanding of HTTP. Once you are familiar with HTTP, all questions of this nature become easily understood.

Comment: File names are only meaningful in context of filesystems. HTTP is not a filesystem.

Comment: When downloading an actual file, a filename is *usually* provided in the response's `Content-Disposition` header. If it is not present, then your only option is to either extract a filename from the URL resource path (yours does not have a filename, though) or else just generate your own local filename. BTW, why are you sending a `Content-Disposition` header in the request? You are not uploading a file, so It doesn't belong there.
Remy Lebeau
25 mins ago